# Is it correct to say "I don't have your voice" on phone?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

What to say when somehow, e.g. because the signal is broken, cannot hear someone's voice for a while and you want to inform them about this?

Is any of these options idiomatic?

- I don't have your voice.
- I don't have your sound.
- I cannot hear your.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options for this. Some that I tend to use often are

> You're breaking up.
>   I can't hear you.
>   I'm only getting every other word you say.
>   I missed half of what you just said.
>   We seem to have a bad phone connection.

The first two options sound quite odd to me so I recommend you don't use them.

Comment: Thanks for the through answer; Indeed, the first two options are direct translation from my language and I doubted that they can be used in English.

Comment: @mok the equivalent in English of the first two would be "I can't hear you".

Answer (score -1):

*'I cannot hear your'* is closest but it should read as - *'I can't hear you'*.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.