# Is it correct to say "Do you have my voice" on phone or online meeting?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

On the phone or online meeting is it correct to say "Do you have my voice?"

Is there any other good alternative?

Comment: There are two problems in this question. First, it's a [duplicate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115434/is-it-correct-to-say-i-dont-have-your-voice-on-phone). Second, your question shows that you didn't do any research beforehand, because if you google "do you have my voice", there are no results of it. I've flagged your post as a duplicate, and hopefully it will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's understandable, but it's not anything I would say, or (I think) any other native English speaker.

I just say "Can you hear me?"

I could say "Can you hear my voice?" but I can't think of a reason to be more specific.

"Have my voice" is just not idiomatic.

To me, "Can you hear?" is much more natural than "Do you hear?" I don't know if that is the case for all English speakers, though.

Comment: 'Can you hear me OK?' is often heard (at least if the speaker has not muted themselves).

Comment: *It's understandable* ???!!!  To ***who**?* The only thing I could think of was in the context of phoning my bank, who told me some years ago that they were going to use ***voice recognition*** in future, so I wouldn't need to keep giving letters from my password every time I phoned them up (but so far as I can tell, they never actually implemented this - presumably because it's to easy for hackers to get round). That sense of ***Can you hear me**?* would simply never have occurred to me.